# How do I call Swift code from Objective-C in a Framework target?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

When you add a Swift file to an Objective-C project, Xcode will generate a Swift-to-ObjC header, as described here: http://ericasadun.com/2014/08/21/swift-calling-swift-functions-from-objective-c/

Without this header it is not possible to call Swift code from Objc-C. However Xcode is not auto-generating this header for my framework target.

If I create an Objective-C *app* and drop a Swift file into it, then it does auto-generate one, so I suspect it's because I'm building a framework and not an app. Without one its not possible to use the Swift code from the Obj-C code.

I tried using the one which was generated for the app (after renaming it and putting it in the appropriate DerivedData folder ) but Xcode didn't update it and actually it will eventually delete it, so manually creating or trying to maintain this file is not feasible.

**How can I make Xcode generate this header for a framework target**, so that I can call my Swift code from my Obj-C code?

And remember folks: the question is about calling Swift from Obj-C not calling Obj-C from Swift.

Comment: What do you need? A bridging header or a generated Obj-C interface?

Comment: I need to be able to add Swift source files to an Obj-C framework and to able to invoke the Swift classes from the Obj-C code.

Comment: And what problem are you having?

Comment: There is no Swift bridging header generated. Without a Swift bridging header it is not possible to call Swift code from Obj-C code within the same code base.

Comment: Interesting, I just set up a test project and there seems to be a catch-22.  Xcode wont generate the "FrameworkName-Swift.h" file unless I specify a bridging header in the Swift compiler build settings, but if I do that then I get an error that "using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported"

Comment: Check this out, it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008123/import-sqlite3-h-error-include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module/32010482#32010482

Comment: This is the correct duplicate link: [Can't use Swift classes inside Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27251979/2792531)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I created a new Framework project, added both Obj-C and Swift files, and was able to do this:

```
// MyObjCClass.m

#import "MyObjCClass.h"
#import <MyFramework/MyFramework-Swift.h>

@implementation MyObjCClass
- (void)test {
    [[MySwiftClass alloc] init];
}
@end
```

Note that your Swift class must be `public`:

```
public class MySwiftClass: NSObject {
    // ...
}
```

More information is available in [Apple's Swift/Obj-C interop documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) under "Importing Swift into Objective-C".

Comment: It seems that the `public` modifier is the key.

Comment: Note that in the documentation I linked, it says: *"[This header] also contains those marked with the `internal` modifier **if your app target has an Objective-C bridging header**."*

Comment: Yeah, I tried `internal` and it didn't work, because you can't have an Objective-C bridging header on a framework

Comment: Before posting the question I also created a new framework and found I could not do likewise with MyFramework-Swift.h as you have done, and my class *was* public. But the difference is I prefaced the class with @objc and interestingly you haven't. I'll do some more experiments without it and see what happens.

Comment: The presence of `@objc` doesn't affect it in my sample project. As far as I can tell, it's necessary to use <angle brackets> when importing the header.

Comment: Same here - As long as I have `public` mine now works with & without `@objc`

Comment: I'm not even clear on what `@objc` even does in Swift exactly... it seems like nonsense.  What is certain is that your class has to inherit from `NSObject` (or obviously something else which eventually can follow up the chain to `NSObject`.

Comment: `@objc` is required in some cases, such as when you require a method to be exposed to the Obj-C runtime by a selector, and/or when you want its Obj-C name to be different from its Swift name.

Comment: @jtbandes It's *not* though.  You can use the `dynamic` keyword for runtime selectors for timers/NSNotifications, etc... (although I forgot about generating different Swift/Objective-C names).

Comment: `dynamic` is for properties only, I think.

Comment: It's not.  I've got a code base with plenty of timers and notifcations and not a single `@objc` in the whole thing.

Comment: OK, I didn't realize `dynamic func` worked. In that case, I have no idea :)

Comment: @nhgrif I [figured out the difference!](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109100/discussion-between-jtbandes-and-nhgrif)

Answer (score -2):

#import <MyFramework/MyFramework-Swift.h>

**ATTENTION: this header file is generated auto！！！！ Don't create it manually!!**